# My Cat is Licking Everything

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, grooming

My cat is around a year old and has had the same bed ever since we've gotten him. Lately, he has been licking the wood frame. I've also seen him lick the wood of his older toys and stuffed animals of mine. There has been no major change in his life, and has gotten lots of attention. Should I be worried? It has not been going on for very long, so I'm wondering if I should wait it out, or look for solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Licking (and gnawing on) inedible materials can be a sign of pica. Pica is caused by psychological stress, but also by nutritional imbalances.

Since your cat has a preference for a very specific material and no history of trauma, I would investigate his diet. Perhaps take him to the vet for a check up and some blood work to narrow down the problem. He might be missing a mineral or something.

In the meantime, I wouldn't stress about it too much. You caught it early and it might very well turn out to be just a behavioral issue. Maybe he just likes the taste.